# How to find all the possible samples of 3 from a population of 5 in Rstudio?

Tags: sampling

I'm trying to find all the possible samples of 3 of this population in Rstudio: 12, 12, 14, 15, 20.

I know by using the combination formula that it will be 10 of them. I want to find all the list using Rstudio. I tried to do it manually but I just get 9 of them:

- 12,12,14
- 12,12,15
- 12,12,20
- 12,14,15
- 12,14,20
- 12,15,20
- 12,14,15
- 12,15,20
- 14,15,20

Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "the combination formula", you presumably mean ${5 \choose 3}=10$.  This suggests you are treating the two $12$s as completely distinct, as otherwise there might only be seven possibilities.

This is also an issue with some R functions but is not difficult to work round by introducing a distinction and then removing it.  For example using `combinations()` from the `gtools` package, you could try something like:

```
library(gtools)
floor(combinations(5, 3, c(12, 12.1, 14, 15, 20)))
```

to get

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   12   12   14
 [2,]   12   12   15
 [3,]   12   12   20
 [4,]   12   14   15
 [5,]   12   14   20
 [6,]   12   15   20
 [7,]   12   14   15
 [8,]   12   14   20
 [9,]   12   15   20
[10,]   14   15   20
```

and, as Quinlan Uyeda has pointed out, your error was to miss the 8th row

Answer (score 2):

You're missing 12 14 20, it should be 8th in your list. The first six start with the first 12, then the next 3 start with the second twelve.

Comment: I think the question is how to write computer code in R language to automatically produce the sample space. Welcome to Math Stack.

Answer (score 1):

In R,

> ```
> combn(c(12,12,14,15,20), 3)
> ```

yields

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
> [1,]   12   12   12   12   12   12   12   12   12    14
> [2,]   12   12   12   14   14   15   14   14   15    15
> [3,]   14   15   20   15   20   20   15   20   20    20
> ```

The results are in the columns.